# CakePHP Migrations: The "template" option does not exist

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am getting following error when executing

```
bin/cake migrations create Initial
```

Error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     The "template" option does not exist.

Plugin is loaded and working.

// Edit: I am using CakePHP 3.0 RC1 fresh installation on a virtualbox with vagrant
Maybe this output helps:

```html
Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/projects/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/Input.php:180
 Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->getOption() at /var/www/projects/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Console/Command/Create.php:130
 Phinx\Console\Command\Create->execute() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/ConfigurationTrait.php:145
 Migrations\Command\Create->execute() at /var/www/projects/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/projects/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/projects/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/projects/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Shell/MigrationsShell.php:70
 Migrations\Shell\MigrationsShell->main() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/Shell.php:387
 Cake\Console\Shell->runCommand() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:200
 Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->_dispatch() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:171
 Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher->dispatch() at /var/www/projects/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php:122
 Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run() at /var/www/projects/bin/cake.php:20
```

I hope you can help me.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that this is a bug in `cakephp/migrations`

Look into:
`/vendor/cakephp/migrations/src/Command/Create.php`

`configure()` is not calling its parent so changes in underlying `phinx` library are not taken into account, namely addition of "template" option which is the problem in this case.

IMO `configure()` should call `parent::configure()` and leave calls of `setName()`, `setDescription()` etc. to `phinx` - there is an issue open here https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/53

Comment: Yes it's a bug, I opened that ticket on github ;-)